# How to get the value after a slash from a URL using javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can I get the value after the very first slash "if a slash is there" from a giving URL?

If the URL is `domain.com` I want to return empty string.

if the URL is `domain.com/index.html` I want to also return an empty sting

If the URL is `domain.com/dev` or `domain.com/dev/new/blah.html` I want to return 'dev'

**Note:** I don't know what will be the values after the first slash

Here is what I have done

```
var icwsSiteBaseURL = document.location.pathname.split("/").slice(1, 2).toString();
```

My code work for the first and third example but will not return an empty string for the second example. It will return `index.html`

Comment: Obviously. You didn't specify, but I assume it returns `index.html`? So, after the line you have, write a simple `if` statement to check for that and set the variable to `''` if it is indeed `index.html`.

Comment: I believe what you want cannot be generalized, so you need to be specific. What if the URL is `domain.com/my.file` where `my.file` is the name of a file, like your `index.html` example. What then separates the two cases? Is it only for `.html`? what about `.css`, `.js`, or files like `hello.world`? And then, how do you know it's not a URL with a separator containing a dot in file name, e.g. `domain.com/index.html/we.like.dots/hello

Comment: @GolezTrol Sorry I just updated my question, instead of an empty string it return `index.html`

Comment: In my question there is note that I don't know what will be the values after the first slash. so `index.html` can be `blah.php` or anything else

Comment: is it specifically index.html that you want to be emtpy? or any page after the first '/'

Comment: @MikeA because you don't know what the values will be after the first slash, why do you expect `dev` (case 3) but not `index.html` (case 2)? They are both values after the first slash.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to check the result for the values you want to ignore. Here is an example:

```js
var domains = [
  'domain.com',
  'domain.com/index.html',
  'domain.com/dev',
  'domain.com/dev/new/blah.html'
  ];

var results = domains.map(function (domain) {
  // This would be document.location.path in your example
  var path = domain.split('/')[1] || '';

  // Check path if it matches the value you want to ignore
  return { domain: domain, result: path === 'index.html' ? '' : path };
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(results, null, 4) + '</pre>');
```

So, for your example code:

```
var icwsSiteBaseURL = document.location.pathname.split("/").slice(1, 2).toString();
if (icwsSiteBaseURL === 'index.html') { icwsSiteBaseURL = ''; }
```